# Use maven even if gradle is present in travis

Tags: maven, gradle, travis-ci

I've added some gradle task to my [project](https://travis-ci.org/easymock/easymock). However, I still want to continuous build to run maven. My first attempt was to add an explicit script

`script:
  - mvn install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -B -V
  - mvn test -B`

This doesn't work. I tried to rename the build.gradle file. This doesn't work either. I probably need to remove gradlew but before that, is there a better solution?